DC isolation - 3 separate circuits with same power source and shared I2C
I am trying to build one small project and based on the needs I need to isolate few components but also keep them connected using I2C. I was doing a research and found few DC DC isolator converters but all of them have some power range - even minimal. I need to have one 5V input which is then splited into 3.
As you can see on the picture I need to have this circuits:

main module, half adum1250, half optocoupler, half adum1250, half optocoupler
Blackbox1, half adum1250 and half optocoupler
Blackbox1, half adum1250 and half optocoupler


This is my idea right now but I am open to new solutions to how full isolate these circuits but use same power source (5V USB), I2C communication and alert pins.
